# Codeception: loop until the element appears on screen

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

Problem:

Some Rooms may be avialable, some may not be aviable at random times.
So I made this loop, and all I need is to stop it when I see this element

```
mod-desired-room__map-overlay hidden
```

Or any other thing that appears when clicking on the room.

Here is the loop:

```
public function pickOneRoom(\AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Pick a Room ');

    $roomCounter = 401;

    $loop = true;

    do{
       $room = '//*[@id="_'.$roomCounter.'"]';

       $I->click($room);
       $roomCounter++;


   }while($loop);

}
```

I need to stop the `$loop` somehow when a given element appears.
I searched a lot and didn't find anything alike.

Comment: Build a condition to set $loop = false; at some point inside the loop.

Comment: Thats also my idea, but i cant figure out how. Since you can't just say ```if($I->See```

Comment: do research the exact happenings when $room = 'blah'; is executed. If I recall correctly, selenium is actually trying to prove that the element you are trying to find exists every time you attempt to assign it and if it doesn't exist it will throw an error and fail. My solution was to use a JS Executor that repeatedly queries the document for elements with a given attribute for a time, pass any found elements into an array, and then act based on what was (or wasn't yet) in the array.

Comment: Can you apply this to my exapme in an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception which gets thrown when an element does not exist. Something like this could be applicable to your case:

```
$elementClicked = false;

do {
    try {
        $I->click("#my-element");
        $elementClicked = true;
    } catch (\Codeception\Exception\ElementNotFound $e) {
        // it's ok, #my-element is not available yet
    }
} while ($elementClicked === false);
```

Basically, `$elementClicked` won't be `true` as long as the `ElementNotFound` exception gets thrown, so the `do/while` loop keep iterating until the `click()` passes.

I'd also add a timeout so the test doesn't get stuck for too long if it cannot click the element for an unreasonably long time:

```
$elementClicked = false;

$timeout = 30;
$timeStart = time();

do {
    if ((time() - $timeStart) > $timeout) {
        throw new \Exception("#my-element did not appear after {$timeout} seconds");
    }

    try {
        $I->click("#my-element");
        $elementClicked = true;
    } catch (\Codeception\Exception\ElementNotFound $e) {
        // it's ok, #my-element is not available yet, wait 1s
        sleep(1);
    }
} while ($elementClicked === false);
```